# Is PHP Serialized Object Data Clean For Mysql Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

Do I need to escape my object data if I'm serializing for mysql injection?

ie:

```
class Object
{
   public $description;
}

$obj = new Object();
$obj->description = mysql_real_escape_string("this is my crazy string with lot's of bad // characters");

$data = serialize($obj); // <-- $data will be stored in DB
```

or will this suffice:

```
class Object
{
   public $description;
}

$obj = new Object();
$obj->description = "this is my crazy string with lot's of bad // characters";

$data = serialize($obj);
```

Comment: FWIW, there should be no apostrophe in "lot's" so it's safe anyway.  (just joking!)

Comment: @Bill lol.  that's hilarious.  I couldn't think of anything to write.  So, you got me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `mysql_real_escape_string()` after you've serialized. That's the string you are going to put in the database after all.

Comment: Always run mysql_real_escape_string on input, or better yet, use prepared statements. The more of a habit you make it, the better.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you must escape it (or use prepared statements).

```
<?php
$obj = (object) array("--'--'" => "--'--");
var_dump(serialize($obj));
```

yields

```
string(44) "O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:6:"--'--'";s:5:"--'--";}"
```

As you can see, there's no escaping.

On a side note, you should use the [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) extension for new code, not the mysql extension.